# How should I set up aiomysql pool cache?

Tags: python, mysql, python-asyncio, aio-mysql

When I use `mysql_pool` from `aiomysql` to update a piece of data, the first time is same as the second time.

```py
class Test(object):
    async def _pool(self):
        self.pool = await aiomysql.create_ç(**mysql_options)

    async def get_one(self, sql, param=None):
        await self.cur.execute(sql, param)
        result = await self.cur.fetchone()
        return result

    async def get(self):
        self.conn = await self.pool.acquire()
        self.cur = await self.conn.cursor(DictCursor)
        sql = '''select policy from tb_user where id = 2;'''
        res = await self.get_one(sql)
        print(res)
        await self.cur.close()
        await self.pool.release(self.conn)

    @staticmethod
    def update():
        import pymysql
        coon = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                               port=3306,
                               user=mysql_options['user'],
                               autocommit=True,
                               password=mysql_options['password'],
                               database=mysql_options['db'])
        cursor = coon.cursor()
        sql = '''update tb_user set policy = 9 where id = 2;'''
        cursor.execute(sql)
        sql = '''select policy from tb_user where id = 2;'''
        cursor.execute(sql)
        data = cursor.fetchone()
        print(data)
    async def run(self):
        await self._pool()
        await self.get()
        self.update()
        await self.get()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Test()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(test.run())
```

version

- python 3.7.0
- aiomysql 0.0.20

Result:

[image]

Comment: I think you forgot a `await coon.commit()` statement after updating the table.

Comment: Also, why are you using `pymysql` instead of `aiomysql` for the update function?

Comment: Provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I use pymysql to simulate any way to update data.

Comment: My operation only involves query and should not need to commit.

Comment: What is the value of `autocommit`?

Comment: @Alex yes, it does need to commit. I just checked it with `aiomysql`. Whenever I don't commit, I get wrong data. Once I start committing in my code, the queries return valid data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit. Run `await conn.commit()` even with mere `SELECT` queries.